# C: How to read a string from a file and assigning it to an element from a structure

Tags: c

The structures are already defined.
I would really appreciate any help.

```
FILE *fptr;
int ch;

fptr("...","r");  
  while ((ch = fgetc(fptr)) != ';'){
    }
strcpy(game->players[0].name,ch);
fclose(fptr);
```

Comment: `fptr("...","r");` --> `fptr = fopen(filename,"r");`, `game->players[0].name=ch` --> `game->players[0].name[i++]=ch;` ... `game->players[0].name[i] = 0;` or `fscanf(fptr, "%[^;]", game->players[0].name);`

Comment: My problem is not reading the string, it is assigning it's value to the structure.

Comment: ch is char type. I guess game->players[0].name is a char[] . So you can use BLUEPIXY answer to do that